# Invalid googleVector elements with JasonSanford / geojson-google-maps (GeoJSON Parser)

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I'm trying to display a few elements from a valid GeoJSON output on Google Maps using the parser recommended by google ( JasonSanford - https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps)

My script is based on the example that is available at the mentioned site and Google's GeoJson support specifications.

The googleVector variable outputs a valid vector, but when iterates through the vector elements, it fails the **currentFeature_or_Features.setMap(map);**

My map variable is a global variable initialized on body onload=initFunc()

This is the error:

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map, and not an
>   instance of StreetViewPanorama

GeoJSON output:

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [ {
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : { },
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [ -59.112137, -37.33122 ]
    }
  }, {
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : { },
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [ -59.150223, -37.330055 ]
    }
  }, {
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : { },
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [ -59.135563, -37.329433 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

Here's the js code:

```
function loadData(geojson){

googleVector = new GeoJSON(JSON.parse(geojson));

if (googleVector.error){
    // Handle the error.
}else{      
    display(googleVector);      
}   
}

function display(currentFeature_or_Features){
if (currentFeature_or_Features.length){
    for (var i = 0; i < currentFeature_or_Features.length; i++){
        if(currentFeature_or_Features[i].length){
            for(var j = 0; j < currentFeature_or_Features[i].length; j++){
                currentFeature_or_Features[i][j].setMap(map);
                if(currentFeature_or_Features[i][j].geojsonProperties) {
                    setInfoWindow(currentFeature_or_Features[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            currentFeature_or_Features[i].setMap(map);
        }
        if (currentFeature_or_Features[i].geojsonProperties) {
            setInfoWindow(currentFeature_or_Features[i]);
        }
    }
}else{
    currentFeature_or_Features.setMap(map);
    if (currentFeature_or_Features.geojsonProperties) {
        setInfoWindow(currentFeature_or_Features);
    }
}
}
```

And the actual image of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHJLc.png

Thanks in advance for any recommendation.

Comment: Where do you create the google.maps.Map object (map)?  If you do create it somewhere, is it in scope inside the "display" function?  The error message says that it doesn't exist...

Comment: It's a global variable initialized on <body onload=initfunct()>, but isn't it the currentFeature..[i] element the wrong one? the function setMap(..) is missing

Comment: If `currentFeature_or_Features[i]` doesn't have a setMap method, then it isn't an overlay that can be added to a Google Maps API v3 map.  Looking at the code, looks like it would be an array of Google Maps API v3 markers, which you could call set map on individually, or you could to pass the Google Maps API v3 map object into the GeoJSON constructor in the options argument.

Comment: Hey, thanks!!! It worked passing the map object to the GeoJSON constructor! Now it leads me to these 2 questions: I copied the same method from the JasonSanford repo example to iterate through vector elements, so how can it fail to do the setMap()? And if I keep this working fix, how'd I send the options params? Can they be previously set to the map object?